# Get ColumnListItem index sapui5

Tags: sapui5

How can I get index of pressed ColumnListItem? I want to get and pass to controller method.

View code:

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
        id: "Countries",
        mode: sap.m.ListMode.None,
        columns: [ new sap.m.Column({
           width: "1em",
           header: new sap.m.Label({
           text: "Name"
           })
        })
        ]
  });
 var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
          id: "first_template",
          type: "Navigation",
          visible: true,
          selected: true,
          cells: [ new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "{name}"
                    })
          ],
          press: [oController.pressListMethod]  
  });
   oTable.bindItems("/eventos", template, null, null);
   oPage.addContent(oTable);
```

Controller code:

```
pressListMethod: function(index){
    var oData = sap.ui.getCore().getModel().getProperty("/eventos/"+index+"/name");
    alert(oData);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn´t rely on the index since the index in the table can differ from the index in your model (e.g. due to filtering and sorting).

You can read the bindingContext of the pressed `ListItem` like this:

```
pressListMethod: function(event){
    var bindingContext = event.getSource().getBindingContext();
}
```

The bindingContext is an artificial object containing the related model and a path of the object within the model.

You can then read properties of your object like this:

```
var name = bindingContext.getProperty("name");
```

To get the whole object you can do it like this:

```
var myObject = bindingContext.getObject();
```

Answer (score -2):

To get exact value of product

```
SelectedRowContext.getObject('PRODUCT_ID')
```

To get Name of product

```
SelectedRowContext.getObject('NAME')
```